# How to install Magento-CE-2.0.2 Full Release with Sample Data?

Tags: magento2

I downloaded Magento-CE-2.0.2 Full Release with Sample Data (ZIP with sample data) from

https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

How can i install  Magento-CE-2.0.2 Full Release with Sample Data (ZIP with sample data) my local Xampp Server.

I try to install from my browser but after 97% complete no progress. I also check my MySQL Database no process running (MySQL Command:SHOW PROCESSLIST).
[http://MyIP/Magento2/setup/#/install]

Screenhot:
[image]

I found error issue Github:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues

Comment: Try this http://alankent.me/2015/07/16/the-dreaded-70-and-98-magento-2-install-pauses-quick-note/

Comment: After change db charset install successfully

Comment: @matinict which db charset you changed for successfull?

Comment: @Muk i can't show dots after 97%, what should i do?

Comment: @GuRu I just drop database & create db from phony admin not change charset. Also delete var+etc ,copy intact this folder from downloaded file . Take time complete install

Comment: @matinict, If you were able to solve this issue, please add that as an answer to the question.